# How to share DataTable between multiple Datagridviews across Application and save precious memory

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a list of companies in DataTable format which is static and accessible across my application.

Different Forms in the application just show filtered Data like Customer Companies ,Supplier Companies ,Misc etc in a DataGridView.

The DataGridViews are just for the sake of displaying the Data.

If I query my companies DataTable for only customer companies and assign the result to DatagridView.Datasource, it will just make a copy and assign it DataGridView.

Imagine if I have a list of 10,000 Customers and User open 10 forms for different purpose, I will be just duplicating 10,000 * 10 rows of data.
Also if my main Companies DataTable is Updated , I will have to update all the DataGridViews too.

Will using DataViews help me save the memory ? 
Will BindingDatasource do good?
or is there any better method to share DataTable without making copies in memory for just Displaying Purpose.

Regards

Comment: *[filter] ... customer companies and assign ... to DatagridView.Datasource, it will just make a copy and assign it DataGridView.* ...I don't believe this is accurate. It would make no sense for a DataTable to be copied for a DataSource - not automatically.

Comment: Thats what I suppose is... I am not clear though

Answer (score 2):

Given:

> I have a list of companies in
>   DataTable format which is static and
>   accessible across my application

I assume 1 `DataTable`. You should use `RowFilter` [*see MSDN: RowFilter*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx):

```
DataGridView customerView;    
DataGridView supplierView;    // initialize in form

DataTable companiesTable;    // initialized and filled

void SetCustomerCompanyView()
{
    DataView cust = new DataView();

    cust.Table = companiesTable;
    cust.RowFilter = "Type = 'Customer'"; 

    customerView.DataSource = cust;
}

//  repeat for SetSupplierCompanyView()
```

If the concern is that one large DataTable is going to be copied throughout multiple active views, then you should really re-think the architecture. If a form is hidden or inactive, you can always dispose of the query results (in worst case) and re-query if/when the form becomes visible or active again (such as a tabbed form). For what it's worth, 10k records is easily handled in most systems and should accommodate several open views (filtered as above) of that DataTable.

**An overtly simplistic comparison:**
You can think of a DataView as a `List<int>` where `int` would be a row index. When you apply a row filter, the appropriate row indexes are appended to the List. You could easily create a view using LINQ to DataSets - extracting the row indexes you require based on a column or columns of data and append to the List. Now you use that list to reference **only** the rows (by `Table.Rows[RowIndex]`) in which you are interested from your primary DataTable.**As stated, this is much simpler functionality than what the `DataView` is *actually* providing.** You have not made a copy of the DataTable - you have simply created a shallow reference mechanism.

Comment: This is exactly what I got while googling, creating DataView and assigning it to the DGVs , just wanted to be certain if there are any more better methods

Comment: I haven't found anywhere that you are actually creating copies...I suspect that the DataView is simply referencing the `.Table` to provide a collection of DataRow references. DataViews are not copies of DataTables.

Comment: If its so then thanks @IAbstract. I will comfortably go with the DataView